# Create a Global Persistent List of Strings as Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, in MS SQL Server Management Studio. I've only ever done Selecting and all the standard stuff but I find myself frequently using the same lists of strings for different queries and I'd like to be able to build variable that holds them. I don't have the access rights to create a new table, otherwise I would just do that. Is this even possible?

Let's say I have a bunch of client numbers that I want to use to include only their client account data with a query, example:

```
SELECT * FROM SALES
WHERE CLIENTNUMBER IN ('123','456','789')
```

Is there a way to create a variable that will hold those 3 values, so that I can instead just say

```
SELECT * FROM SALES
WHERE CLIENTNUMBER IN @CLOTHING_CLIENTS
```

The list is longer than 3 client numbers of course. And there are different categories etc. I think it would be MUCH simpler to do as a separate table but of course I don't have the ability to create new tables. I could do `JOIN`s and the like too but that's getting even more work than just putting in the client numbers each time.

I'm trying to simplify things and make it more readable for other people, not make it more efficient for the database or more "correct".

Comment: Afaik, there is no way to create a global variable in tsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this involving temp tables or table variables. Try something like this:

```
declare @CLOTHING_CLIENTS table (ClientNumber varchar(20) not null);

-- Your list of values goes here
insert into @CLOTHING_CLIENTS (ClientNumber)
values ('123')
      ,('456')
      ,('789');

select * from Sales
where ClientNumber in (select ClientNumber from @CLOTHING_CLIENTS);
```

The @CLOTHING_CLIENTS variable can be used again anywhere in the same batch that it was created in. [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69217/table-variable-and-database-scope) does a good job explaining the scope of table variables.

Answer (score 0):

Good news there are Global things in T-SQL!!!

An extension of Jeff Lewis's answer that makes things a bit more 'Global' is to use the ## Type of table.

Assuming you can make them then a ##Table is a temporary table that can be access by other connections and even other databases. Just make sure your on the same server.

So you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##MyValues(A INT)
INSERT INTO ##MyValues(A) VALUES (1)
```

Once done you can go anywhere and do

```
SELECT * FROM ##MyTables
```

Now all you need to do is update your snippets to do things like

```
SELECT * FROM SALES AS S
INNER JOIN ##MyClientIDTable AS MCIT OM MCIT.CLIENTNUMBER = S.CLIENTNUMBER
```

Just make sure your ##MyClientIDTable Has a CLIENTNUMBER column in it and the correct data.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. What's the difference between ## and @ for temp tables? Is @ limited in scope to the current query, while ## is global within the same server? How long does the ## table stick around before being cleaned up?

Comment: the (@) is a local variable. so a @Table follows all the rules as any other data type  (only usable in the proc, and will die when the proc end  # is a real table made in the tempdb again like (@)tables it can only be used in the scope of the proc and will die at the end of the proc. Its a bit better though as you get the full power of indexs and statistics. a ## is a real table made in the tempdb the same as #tables BUT its douse not die at the end of the proc and anyone who knows its name can use it.